# phpactiverecord association through a second table

Tags: php, has-many-through, phpactiverecord

Ok, I'm hoping to be able to properly explain this, so here goes. I'm using phpActiveRecord and trying to create a specific association through another association. It's not exactly a many to many with a linking table, as I've been able to create those without any real problems. Let me give you the details...

This was an already existing database schema and was not designed with AR in mind when naming the tables or the fields. All tables were in a singular reference and all fields referencing other tables are prefixed with 'fk_' and do not follow a normal naming schema. The association is from an Article to a Website to a Client. Clients can have many websites, Websites can have many Articles. The goal is to be able to reference a Client from an Article through the Website. So far, this is what I have:

```
Client
  $has_many (
    array('websites', 'foreign_key' => 'fk_client_id')
  )

Website
  $belongs_to (
    array('client', 'foreign_key' => 'fk_client_id')
  )
  $has_many (
    array('articles', 'foreign_key' => 'fk_website_id_client')
  )

Article
  $belongs_to (
    array('client_website', 'class_name' => 'Website', 'foreign_key' => 'fk_website_id_client'),
    array('client', 'through' => 'client_website')
  )
```

I've simplified some of the code, so no, I'm not forgetting the '=' signs or anything like that. Now, accessing the `client_website` returns the proper object, so that association works. Drilling down the opposite direction also works, I can see multiple websites per client, and multiple articles through website. This seems like it should work fine... that I'm just missing something basic, yet I can't seem to find it. I have a feeling it's an issue with the field names being labelled oddly, but I'm unable to verify that.

Thanks for any help on this!

Comment: What are the id's of the tables called? you didn't specifically mention them in your associations?

Comment: Table names are `client`, `website`, `website_article` respectively, and yes they are singular table names (Not by my choice, it was already like that). Each table has a primary key called `id`. Aside from that, not sure exactly what other id's you're looking for.  I left out the `static $table_name = 'table_here'` for the sake of the post since I figured it was irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Well, I was just looking for the `id` field: if they had a different name, your associations need to include the `"id" => "yourid"` field, I don't think they do really, definately not if they're called 'id', but just to be sure ;)

Comment: The `id` field on each table is just `id` (thank god)... only the foreign keys are labelled in a way that doesn't play well with AR.